# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So i am New to Asp and MVC and i am using a Lambda Expression In order to sort a list and take the tiop five but i keep getting a The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+d__3a error please help my code is below

```
public ActionResult Queue()
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var form = context.Forms..OrderBy(c => c.Date).ToList().Take(5);

        return View(form);

    }

 [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date Visited")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }



 <tbody>
    @foreach (var form in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.ActionLink("view", "AdminApproval", new { id = form.FormId })

            </td>

            <td>
                @form.Submitter
            </td>

            <td>
                HomeClub
            </td>

            <td>
                @form.ClubVisited
            </td>

            <td>
                @form.Date
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

As by default LINQ uses deferred execution i.e code is actually executed when iterating through items.

```
Take - Use the Take<TSource> operator to return a given number of elements in a sequence and then skip over the remainder.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use `ToList` - `The ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List<T> that contains the query results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy of the query results.`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

We need to return actual collection to View. So call `Take(5)` first then call `ToList()`

```
return View(context.Forms.OrderBy(c => c.Date).Take(5).ToList())
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=750

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var form = context.Forms.OrderBy(c => c.Date).ToList().Take(5);
```

To:

```
var form = context.Forms.OrderBy(c => c.Date).Take(5).ToList();
```